# How do I tell if a function is continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Is the function $f(x)=9-x^2$ continuous?

1.Lets say for $x=1$

$f(1)= 9-1=8$

2.$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (9-x^2)= 9-1 = 8$

3.So  $f(a) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) $

Does this mean that the function is continuous ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity? Did you learn that polynomial functions are continuous?

Comment: A function that is continuous in a particular point doesn't have to be continuous everywhere.

Comment: yes but it should be continuous in all its domain right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got the right steps for the continuity of $f$ at the point $x = 1$.  To generalise it to any point $x = a$, change $1$ to $a$ in the above steps.

1. $f(a) = 9-a^2$
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} (9 - x^2) \stackrel{(*)}{=} 9-a^2$
3. so $f(a) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$.

Since the choice of $a \in \Bbb R$ is arbitrary, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

We have (*) since for any $\epsilon > 0$, we take $\delta = \min((2|a|+1)^{-1} \epsilon, 1)$.  For any $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|x+a| \le |x| + |a| < (|a| + \delta) + |a| \le 2|a| + 1$.
$$|(9-x^2)-(9-a^2)| = \dots = |x+a||x-a| < (2|a|+1)\delta < \epsilon$$

Comment: I think your step 2 is incorrect, it seems like you were using the fact that $f$ is continuous at $a$ to get the value.

Comment: @Botond Thanks for your comment.  Fixed this circular argument by introducing a ([tag:epsilon-delta]) argument.

Comment: I cant understand the epsilon delta thing

Comment: @EndritShabani That's not necessary.  In fact, [basic arithmetic of limits](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html) will do.  I add this for Botond.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to explicitly walk you through the answer because this looks like a homework question and it's important that the solution you come up with is your own so I'm only going to provide you with some direction.

In regards to the steps you walked through, you proved that a limit exists at $x=1$, which as a result means that $f(x)$ continuous at $x=1$, which is true. However, your steps only prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$ and not for any domain $D$.

For that, you will need to prove that for every $n \in D$ a limit exists at $n$, or you could show that the derivative of $f(x)$ is defined in the domain $D$.

To prove that for every $n \in D$ a limit exists at $n$, you just need to prove the following,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to n} f(x) = f(n)$$

---

As a side note, this informal definition of continuity may help you grasp the concept a little better.

If you can draw the graph of $f(x)$ along the domain $D$ without taking your pencil off the paper, then $f(x)$ is continuous along $D$.

Comment: how can I prove that for every n  in D  a limit exists ?

Comment: Apologies @EndritShabani , my earlier comment was misguided. Please refer to the answer above, I edited it to answer your question.

Comment: the functions are continuous in their domain right ?

Comment: hmm, I'm not quite sure what you mean. In order to declare a function continuous, there needs to be some domain associated with the function.

Comment: yes I meant the function is continuous for every n that is element of its domain

Comment: that is correct.